# How to deserialize dictionary with hierarchical keys to dynamic object?

Tags: .net, dynamicobject

I'm receiving data in dictionary form and would like to deserialize it into a dynamic object.  The twist is the dictionary keys express a hierarchical object.  A second twist is some of the keys express an array and/or dictionary property.

For example:

```
===========Key================ ======Value========
Person.First                  | John
Person.Last                   | Doe
Person.Phone[Work]            | 999-555-1234
Person.Phone[Home]            | 999-555-1235
Person.Addresses[Home].Street | 101 My Street
Person.Addresses[Home].City   | AnyTown
Person.Spouse.First           | Jane
Person.Spouse.Last            | Doe
Person.Insurance[0].Name      | Medicare
Person.Insurance[0].GroupNum  | 1234567
```

**Edit**: Added array examples

I'm trying to find a simple method to create an object that can then be used in a runtime   expressions evaluator.

Here's my first attempt that works for the simple properties, but doesn't attempt to handle the arrays

```
public static class DynamicBuilder
{
    public static object Build(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
    {

        ExpandoObject root = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            var objDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)root;

            var parts = item.Key.Split('.');

            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length ; i++)
            {
                string propName = parts[i];

                if (i < parts.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (!objDict.ContainsKey(propName))
                    {
                        dynamic temp = new ExpandoObject();
                        objDict.Add(propName, temp);
                        objDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)temp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)objDict[propName];
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (objDict.ContainsKey(propName))
                        objDict[propName] = item.Value;
                    else
                        objDict.Add(propName, item.Value);

                }

            }

        }

        return root;
    }

}
```

Any ideas on better way to approach this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are there actually array properties in the data? In your example you've only shown dictionary properties and I just want to make sure you're not confusing array definition with dictionary access.

Comment: yes..I'll update the sample with the array example

Comment: Looks like a reasonable approach. Maybe one thing: you should split that method into smaller ones to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be just to make a custom object like

```
public class DictObject
{
   public String value;
   public Dictionary<string, DictObject> children;
}
```

Your main dictionary would just be a `Dictionary<string, DictObject>` object. For each property name you would add a dictionary entry and a value, or a child dictionary for the children.

So you would load up `Person.First` so that it would be accessed like

```
 MainDict("Person").children("First").Value
```

And using that approach, you could simple represent your dictionary and array entries the same way as the `.` children as well, instead of treating them special. Visualize your data like this,

```
===========Key================ ======Value========
Person.First                  | John
Person.Last                   | Doe
Person.Phone.Work             | 999-555-1234
Person.Phone.Home             | 999-555-1235
Person.Addresses.Home.Street  | 101 My Street
Person.Addresses.Home.City    | AnyTown
Person.Spouse.First           | Jane
Person.Spouse.Last            | Doe
Person.Insurance.0.Name       | Medicare
Person.Insurance.0.GroupNum   | 1234567
```

So the values would be accessed like,

```
 MainDict("Person").children("Insurance").children("0").children("Name").Value
```

And you could always add properties to the `DictObject` if you wanted to track dictionary/array if you wanted to output that same text file again.